# How to find or create Ontologies for specific domain?

Tags: python, semantic-web, ontology

**Objective**

I am trying to build an Ontology-based semantic search engine specific to our data.

**Problem Statement**

Our data is just a bunch of sentences and what I want is to give a phrase and get back the sentences which are:

Similar to that phrase

- Has a part of a sentence that is similar to the phrase
- A sentence which is having contextually similar meanings

Let me try giving you an example suppose I search for the phrase "Buying Experience", I should get the sentences like:

- I never thought car buying could take less than 30 minutes to sign and buy.
- I found a car that I liked and the purchase process was straightforward and easy
- I absolutely hated going car shopping, but today I’m glad I did

The search term will always be one to three-word phrases. Ex: buying experience, driving comfort, infotainment system, interiors, mileage, performance, seating comfort, staff behavior.

**Implementation explored already**

OpenSemanticSearch
AWS Comprehend

**Current Implementation**

Right now I am exploring one implementation ('Holmes Extractor') which mostly suites the objective I am trying to achieve. For my use case, I am using 'Topic Matching' available in Holmes.

Holmes has already incorporated many important concepts in its design such as NER, pronoun resolution, word embedding based similarity, ontology-based extraction, which makes this implementation even more promising.

**What I have tried so far on Holmes**

1. Manually curated a labeled set with sentences
2. Registered and serialized our dataset with unique label id for each document (sentence)
3. For comparison prepared a template to get precision, recall, and f1_score of each iteration of running queries (search query is the same as the label)
4. Using spaCy's 'en_core_web_lg' for word embedding

Score template looks something like:
Query | Predicted Rows | Actual Number of rows in the queried set | Precision | Recall | f1_score

5. Please find below the parameters used in each iteration. For all the iterations, generated the scores for Manager.overall_similarity_threshold in range(0.0 to 1.0) and topic_match_documents_returning_dictionaries_against.embedding_penalty in range(0.0 to 1.0)

**Iteration 1:**

Without any Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=False

**Iteration 2:**

Without any Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=True

*Build a custom Ontology using Protege, which is specific to our data set*

**Iteration 3:**

With custom Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=False, Ontology.symmetric_matching=True

**Iteration 4:**

With custom Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=True, Ontology.symmetric_matching=True

At this stage, I can observe that

custom Ontology,

Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=True,

Manager.overall_similarity_threshold in range (0.6-0.8),

topic_match_documents_returning_dictionaries_against.embedding_penalty in range in range(0.6-0.8),

together are producing very strong scores.

*average scores for 0.8 -> precision: 0.78, recall: 0.712, f1_score: 0.738*

*average scores for 0.7 -> precision: 0.738, recall: 0.7435, f1_score: 0.726*

Still, results are not that accurate even after providing custom ontology, because of a lack of stemming keywords in the Ontology graph.

For example, if in Ontology we have given something like Mileage->fuel efficiency, fuel economy

Holmes will not match sentences with fuel efficient under Mileage, since "fuel efficient" is not mentioned in the Graph

**Iteration 5:**

With custom Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=False, Ontology.symmetric_matching=False

**Iteration 6:**

With custom Ontology and Manager.embedding_based_matching_on_root_words=True, Ontology.symmetric_matching=False

**Iteration 7:**

Along with Iteration 4 parameters, and  
topic_match_documents_returning_dictionaries_against.tied_result_quotient in range(0.9 to 0.1)

Again results are better in 0.8-0.9 range

**Iteration 8:**

I had pre-downloaded ontologies from a few sources:

Automobile Ontology:

https://github.com/mfhepp/schemaorg/blob/automotive/data/schema.rdfa

Vehicle Sales Ontology:

http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/vso/ns

Product Ontology:

http://www.productontology.org/dump.rdf

Mesh Thesaurus:

https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data/dataset/eurovoc

English thesaurus:

https://github.com/mromanello/skosifaurus

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mromanello/skosifaurus/master/thesaurus.rdf

General Ontologies:

https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/collections/pre-release-2019-08-30

https://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-04#dbpedia-ontology

https://lod-cloud.net/dataset/dbpedia

https://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/ontology

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#English_Wikipedia

https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-exports/rdf/

All the above ontologies are available in either ttl, n3 or rdf format. And holmes extractor (implicitly RDFlib) works on OWL syntax. Therefore, the conversion of the given formats to the OWL format for heavy files is another challenge.

I have tried loading the first 4 ontologies on Holmes after conversion to OWL. But the conversion process takes time as well. Also, loading big ontologies on Holmes itself is taking a good amount of time.

As per Holmes documentation, Holmes works best with the ontologies that have been built for specific subject domains and use cases.

**What next**

The challenges which I am facing here are:

1. Finding the proper Ontologies available around customer experience in the automobile domain
2. Making the conversion process of ontologies faster
3. How can we easily generate the domain-specific ontology from our existing data
4. Configuring the right set of parameters along with Ontology to get more accurate results for search phrase queries

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help in advance